# Direction and Distance to a line which goes from location A to location B

Tags: trigonometry

I have two location specified in latitude and longitude. Between these location is a line (bearing). I am at a third location. How do I determine how far I am away from this line and in what direction the closed point to it is from where I am?

Answer (score 0):

In general (no specific formulas), let A and B be the two locations. You need to find an equation for the line going through A and B, call this Equation 1.  Then, find an equation for the line going through point C (the point you are at, the third location) and having slope perpendicular (negative reciprocal) to the line going through A and B.  Call this Equation 2.  The distance between the intersection of these two lines and the point C at which you are standing is the shortest distance from you to the line, and the direction will be given by the slope of Equation 2.

Comment: So the answer to the question is......go find an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have two points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$. Use $m =\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ to find slope. Then $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$. This is the equation of the line passing from $A$ and $B$. You are standing at $C (x_3, y_3)$, Now use formula
$$\text{dist} =\dfrac{|ax_3+by_3+c|}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}}$$